# overlap notification badge on glyph in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a comment/notification setup in bootstrap, and can't seem to get the alignment right.

I'm going for a pretty common layout as in this screenshot:

[image: Notify]

...but I can't get it to lignup. **[Here's a Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7o1VlsuzxY)** of my attempt.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-link" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.badge-notify{
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.badge-notify{
   background:red;
   position:relative;
   top: -20px;
   left: -35px;
}


<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-link" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
</div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/7teIvGLIzY

Comment: A more "bootstrap" way to do this would be to use `<div class="btn-group">` rather than the `container`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing the point of view that [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) is a better way to do this task.
However, I offer you these snippets to make this approach work:

```
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-link" style="font-size:36px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
    </div>

   .badge-notify{
     background:red;
     position:relative;
     -moz-transform: translate(-100%, -100%); /* For Firefox */
     -ms-transform: translate(-100%, -100%); /* for IE */
     -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -100%); /* For Safari, Chrome, iOS */
     -o-transform: translate(-100%, -100%); /* For Opera */
```

Tip: it might be useful to play with percentage values inside translate's brackets for the best result. Moreover, you can try using many other effects like 3D, rotating and so on.

Answer (score -1):

For dynamism, I'd like to mention the usage of `transform` instead of relying on trial/error of pixels (which might still be of your use, depending on the use case)

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-link" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
</div>

.badge-notify{
   background:red;
   position:relative;
   transform: (-100%, -100%);
}
```

This will position the badge just touching to the button. Depending on how much overlapping you want, decrease the x value. eg., for half of the badge - `transform: (-150%, -100%)` would be ideal.