# How to use glyphicon on top of bootstrap badge in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show glyphicon on the top of bootstrap badge.

Can anyone share the css for the same.

I need glyphicon to be placed at the top of badge like given below

[image]

PS: I need glyph over (on the top corner of the badge)

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <span class="badge">10</span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
           
        
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your current code?

Comment: have you tried font-awesome

Comment: Put Your Code For More Clarification

Comment: @AatifBandey No i am using bootstrap glyphicon

Comment: I think you should try it might help you.

Comment: @AatifBandey Bootstrap will also give same result.I want to avoid using font awesome for the same reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overlap notification badge on glyph in Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790721/overlap-notification-badge-on-glyph-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: @grillcsirke That is badge over glyph..I need vice versa

Comment: It's exactly the same image as the one in the duplicate Q.

Comment: @worldofjr..Image might be same but I need glyph over badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.badge {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.badge > .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="badge">10 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is what I am looking for..but it is showing square glyph..I need round glyph

Comment: Updated `snippet`, check once

Answer (score 1):

You can try below css.

It is working for me

```
.badge > .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.badge {
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```css
.group .glyphicon.glyphicon-time {
    left: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
}
.group .badge {
    margin-top: 10px;
   position: relative;
}
.group{ }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="group">
          <span class="badge">10</span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
           </div>
        
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer @dhaarani...But this is not what I needed..I need to show glyph on the top of badge

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this code and result will look like this [image]

```
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="badge-container" style="
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
">
            <span class="badge">10</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="
    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    top: -5px;
"></span>
        </div>


    </div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.glyphicon{
     top: 24px !important;
    font-size: 31px;

}
.badge {
margin-left: -10px;
background-color: #E91E63 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
         
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
           <span class="badge">10</span>

        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```